# $n=0$ mode Fourier expansion on string theory

Tags: string-theory, compactification, kaluza-klein

I am quite baffled at what the $n=0$ mean in compactification, why is this mode important?
[image]

I mean if $n=0$ was applied here we'd just be left with
[image]

I know that (39) holds from (37), but I can't figure out why (38) is of particular significance.

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: I'm note too confident in this context, but generally speaking $n=0$ is the center-of-mass motion

Answer (score 1):

In the usual Kaluza-Klein reduction for scalar fields in $D$ dimension you got an infinite tower of scalar fields from the $D-1$ dimensional point of view. These scalars come with increasing mass labelled by an integer $n$.

The case $n=0$ is special, because is the massless case. For instance in String Theory, when you compactify on a torus, a consistent truncation of your theory is to consider only the massless field, that is looking at the Supergravity approximation.